# PDFsharp save to MemoryStream

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, stream, pdfsharp

I want to save a PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument by its Save method to a Stream, but it doesn't attach the PDF header settings to it. So when I read back the Stream and return it to the user, he see that the PDF file is invalid. Is there a solution to attach the PDF header settings when PDFsharp saves to memory?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

So the solution:

```
MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Document doc = new MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Document();
MigraDoc.Rendering.DocumentRenderer renderer = new DocumentRenderer(doc);
MigraDoc.Rendering.PdfDocumentRenderer pdfRenderer = new MigraDoc.Rendering.PdfDocumentRenderer();
pdfRenderer.PdfDocument = pDoc;
pdfRenderer.DocumentRenderer = renderer;
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
  pdfRenderer.Save(ms, false);
  byte[] buffer = new byte[ms.Length];
  ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
  ms.Flush();
  ms.Read(buffer, 0, (int)ms.Length);
}
```

There is this MigraDoc stuff which comes with PdfSharp, but i hardly found any proper doc/faq for it. After hours of googling i've found a snippet which was something like this. Now it works.

Comment: What's pDoc? Is that the same as doc?

Comment: it worked for me like this:
pdfRenderer.Document = doc; 
pdfRenderer.RenderDocument(); 
pdfRenderer.PdfDocument.Save(stream);

Answer (score 63):

If you think there is an issue with PdfDocument.Save, then please report this on the PDFsharp forum (but please be more specific with your error description).
Your "solution" looks like a hack to me.
"pdfRenderer.Save" calls "PdfDocument.Save" internally.
Whatever the problem is - your "solution" still calls the same Save routine.

Edit:
To get a byte[] containing a PDF file, you only have to call:

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
document.Save(stream, false);
byte[] bytes = stream.ToArray();
```

Early versions of PDFsharp do not reset the stream position.

So you have to call

```
ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

to reset the stream position before reading from the stream; this is no longer required for current versions.

Using ToArray can often be used instead of reading from the stream.

Edit 2: instead of `stream.ToArray()` it may be more efficient to use `stream.GetBuffer()`, but this buffer is usually larger than the PDF file and you only have to use `stream.Length` bytes from that buffer. Very useful for method that take a `byte[]` along with a length parameter.

Answer (score 23):

I found simpler solution:

```
byte[] fileContents = null; 
using(MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream()) 
{ 
    pdfDoc.Save(stream, true); 
    fileContents = stream.ToArray(); 
}
```

Source:
http://usefulaspandcsharp.wordpress.com/2010/03/09/save-a-pdf-to-a-byte-array-using-pdf-sharpmigradoc/

Comment: My answer shows since 2010 that `ToArray()` can be used. ;-)

Answer (score 7):

For MigraDoc (ver 1.30) I could save it with

```
PdfDocumentRenderer renderer = new PdfDocumentRenderer(true, PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfFontEmbedding.Always);
renderer.Document = report.m_Document;

renderer.RenderDocument();


using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    renderer.PdfDocument.Save(stream, false);
    ... your code in here

}
```

Answer (score -2):

Thanks Misnyo Solution. But for me it works like this:

```
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfDocumentRenderer pdfRenderer = new PdfDocumentRenderer();   

        //Add to document here.......

        //render the document with pdf renderer
        pdfRenderer.Document = document;
        pdfRenderer.RenderDocument();

        //Save renderer result into stream   
        using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            pdfRenderer.PdfDocument.Save(ms, false);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[ms.Length];
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            ms.Flush();
            ms.Read(buffer, 0, (int)ms.Length);
            ms.Position = 0;
        }
```