# Show PDF from SQL Server database using C#

Tags: c#, database, pdf, sql-server-2012, visual-studio-2019

I want to display a `.pdf` that I have already uploaded into my SQL Server database, but I need it to be shown in the form and directly from the database (without saving it into my computer).

I'm using SQL Server 2012 and Visual Studio 2019.

I tried to used AxAcroPdf, but I don't know how it works.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlCommand show = new SqlCommand("SELECT documento FROM table WHERE p = '" + contentP + "'AND n = '" + contentN + "' AND documento is not null;", con);
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(show);
adapter.Fill(dt);

if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
   byte[] ap = (byte[])dt.Rows[0]["documento"];
   MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(ap);

   var axacropdf = new AcroPDFLib.AcroPDF();
   axacropdf.LoadFile(ap.ToString());
   axacropdf.setShowToolbar(true);
   axacropdf.setView("Fit");
}
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: @Cleptus I was using PDFSharp, but I am going to try that library, thank you

Comment: @luciacar I was telling you that AcroPDF **could not** do it. PDFSharp looks like it can do it. [Check this PDFSharp answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1078941/2265446)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution for my problem:

I installed the nuget `Syncfusion.PdfViewer.Windows`

Then I added a pdf viewer from the ToolBox called `PdfDocumentView`

And I put the next code, adding the SqlConnection at the beginning:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlCommand verDoc = new SqlCommand("SELECT documento FROM inspeccionGestionDocumental WHERE placa = '" + contenidoPlaca + "'AND numeroPropuesta = '" + contenidoNumeroPropuesta + "' AND documento is not null;", con);
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(consultar);
adapter.Fill(dt);

if(dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
   byte[] ap = (byte[])dt.Rows[0]["documento"];
   MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(ap);
   pdfDocumentView1.Load(ms);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is better not to use adobe reader for this purpose since

1. It has to be installed on the client PC
2. It is a COM automation server component which is extremely slow

Instead, use nuget to get this:
https://github.com/pvginkel/PdfiumViewer
package.

Comment: Thank you, I am going to try that package

Answer (score 1):

Based on my test, It seems that AcroPDF doesn't support load the byte array to show the pdf in winform.

I find another method to show pdf from the database directly.

First, please try to install the following nuget->`ceTe.DynamicPDF.Viewer.NET`.

Second, please add a control called `pdfviewer` from the Toolbox.

Third, you can try the following code to load the pdf from the byte array in winform.

```
        string connstr = "connstr";
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connstr);
        connection.Open();
        string sql = "select * from PdfReader";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(table);
        if (table.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            byte[] ap = (byte[])table.Rows[0]["Content"];
            PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(ap);
            pdfViewer1.Open(pdfDocument);
        }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. The problem is that my program is going to be part of a public application, so I need it to be a free open source

Comment: @luciacar, based on my search, ceTe.DynamicPDF.Viewer.NET is a free open source. You could look at the [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ceTe.DynamicPDF.Viewer.NET/). Sentence: Flexible licensing (including royalty free) is available to meet all your needs.

Comment: I've found another pdf viewer and now I can show the pdf without having it in the computer. I'm going to publish that solution.